# How do I achieve lazy loading via a CDN and use dynamic query parms in requireJS?

Tags: dynamic, requirejs

I have spent far too long on this problem. I am amazed that it is so difficult to achieve.

**WORKS**

```
define('mapAPI',

    ['googleLoader'],

    function (G) {
        // Google is good to go
    }
);

define('googleLoader',

    ['async!http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true'],

    function(){
        return window.google.maps;
    }
);
```

**DOES NOT WORK**

```
define('mapAPI',
    ['require'],

    function (require) {
        (function () {
            require('googleLoader')
        }());
    }
);

define('googleLoader',
    ['async!http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true'],

    function(){
        return window.google.maps;
    }
);
```

> Error: Module name 'googleLoader' has not been loaded yet for context: _
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded

***ALSO DOES NOT WORK***

```
define('mapAPI',
    ['googleLoader'],

    function (G) {
        // Google is good to go
    }
);

define(
    ['require'],

    function (require){
        require(['async!http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true']);

        return window.google.maps; //undefined
    }
);
```

> "NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://localhost:8000/public/example/async.js"

If the async plugin is not used, the module and dependent module will continue executing before the script has loaded.

**STILL, DOES NOT WORK**

```
define('googleLoader',

    [],

    function () {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&callback=gCB';
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

        return (function load() {
            if (window.google) {
                var G = window.google;
                return G;
            }
            else {
                setTimeout(load, 50);
            }
        }());
    }
```

);

In this case, it is as if the return statement doesn't wait for the anon function to resolve before it executes.